# Like Button: Pass Certain Variable from PHP to Jquery when Clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this simple php code that displays all users' posts with all of them having a unique **'like'** button:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $post_content = $row['content'];
  $post_id = $row['id'];

  echo $post_content ."<br/>";
  echo "<a href = '#' id = 'likebutton' onclick = 'like_add($post_id )>Like</a>";
}
```

And my javascript:

```
function like_add(post_id){
  alert(post_id); //to test if the link is working
}
```

I got this error however:

> ReferenceError: 2dg7c is not defined

Here `2dg7c` is an id of a post in which I clicked `LIKE`.
Did I missed something?

Comment: did you try "like_add('$post_id')" ??

Comment: Actually, I should throw a syntax error, right? Something like: *SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal*.

Comment: `echo "<a href = '#' id = 'likebutton' onclick = 'like_add($post_id )>Like</a>";` in this line `$post_id` is a string and you are passing without quotes so it will not work. you have to use `\\`

Comment: One thing you need to do is remove spaces are `=` signs.

Comment: Someone please :(

Comment: try this  echo "<a href = '#' id = 'likebutton' onclick = 'like_add(\"{$post_id}\")'>Like</a>";

Comment: @JYoThI I tried it.. it didn't do anything nor produced any errors...

Comment: Incidentally, you're not passing to jQuery, you're passing to JavaScript. Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: it's working for me . i think you have some other problem @Dranreb

Comment: If you keep getting an error about 'unexpected expression }' then you are forgetting the semi-colon at the end of your echo.

Comment: @JayBlanchard No sir I have a `;` at the end of my echo

Comment: while i posted this as a comment while you said not working   echo "<a href='#' id='likebutton' onclick='like_add(\"{$post_id}\")'>Like</a>";  but same answer accepted now . how it is working now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change link code like this:-

```
echo "<a href='#' id='likebutton' onclick='like_add(\"{$post_id}\")'>Like</a>";
```

Comment: I got an error like this bro ` expected expression, got '}'`

Comment: On the first one,, I got an `illegal character` error. The second one was my original code which is not working..

Comment: I followed the second one and still got this error : `ReferenceError: 2dg7c is not defined` ... Can you post a working snippet of this issue sir? Maybe something's just really wrong with my codes

Comment: @Dranreb  glad to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Always try to pass value in quotes.

```
echo "<a href = '#' id = 'likebutton' onclick = 'like_add('".$post_id."' )'>Like</a>";
```

Comment: it wil not work. Because `onclick` event started with using `'`. And you trying to do this -> `onclick='like_add('2dg7c')'`

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the double quotes using `slash (\)` like this

```
echo "<a href ='#' id ='likebutton' onclick='like_add(\"{$post_id}\")'>Like</a>";
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use like this"?  A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I really would also remove the spaces around the `=`, but this works. Surprised at others not testing their code.There is a space on both sides of the `=`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`echo "<a href = '#' id = 'likebutton' onclick = 'like_add(\"$post_id\")'>Like</a>";`

You should add `"` before passing the argument to function. In your state, javascript thinks you referencing a variable as argument. But you want to send string.

Comment: Try this :  echo "<a href = '#' id = 'likebutton' onclick = 'like_add($post_id )>Like</a>";

Answer (score 2):

You just missed to close single quote here

```
echo "<a href = '#' id = 'likebutton' onclick = 'like_add($post_id)>Like</a>";
```

Just replace the above with

```
echo "<a href = '#' id = 'likebutton' onclick = 'like_add(\"$post_id\")'>Like</a>";
```

Comment: I got this error bro = expected expression, got '}'

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
echo '<a href = "#" id = "likebutton" onclick = "like_add({$post_id})">Like</a>';
```

### Reason :

There is a problem of concatenation. 
Php variable is not binding in string. To bind it we can break the long string and concatenate by dot. or use {} or use heredocs.

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Did not worked either man,, gave me an error.. I think it's because of the  "

Comment: @JayBlanchard updating my answer

Comment: Your code returns this `<a href = "#" id = "likebutton" onclick = "like_add({$post_id})">Like</a>`. Please test before posting an answer. The variable does not get parsed.

Comment: inside the single quotes everything  is consider as  a string

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should write

```
echo "<a href='#' id='likebutton' onclick=like_add('".$post_id."')>Like</a>";
```